# Datatables from a raw query

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, datatables

I have a datatable in a view that is server processing as the table has several thousand records. I have attempted to use eloquent to get the data but by faw the easiest is a raw SQL.

My view is

```
<table id="thetable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="90%" align="center" cellspacing="5px" cellpadding="10px" >
        <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>PartNo</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>ManufacturerName</th>       
        <th>accountcode</th>

        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
     $('#thetable').DataTable({
                dom: 'lBfrtip',
                "iDisplayLength": 30,
                "lengthMenu": [ 10, 25,30, 50, 75, 100,200 ],
                buttons: [
                    'copy',  'print',
                    {extend: 'excel',
                        filename: 'PartDetails', footer:true},
                    {extend: 'pdf',
                        filename:  'PartDetails'},
                    {extend:'csvHtml5',
                        filename: 'PartDetails'},
                    {extend: 'collection',
                        text: 'columns',
                        buttons:['columnsVisibility'] }
                ],
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: 
                    {url: ' {{ route('partdetails.serverSide') }}',
                    type: 'GET' }


    }) ;
 </script>
```

My data is supplied by

```
Route::get('/partdetails/serverSide',[
    'as' => 'partdetails.serverSide',
   'uses' => function(){
        $parts = DB::select('SELECT partdetails.ID, partdetails.PartNo, partdetails.Description, manufacturer.Manufacturer AS ManufacturerName, partdetails.accountcode FROM partdetails INNER JOIN manufacturer ON partdetails.Manufacturer = manufacturer.entry ORDER BY partdetails.PartNo ASC');
        return Datatables::of($parts)->make();
    }
```

If I dd the $parts it is all correct and myh columns in datatables are perfectly correct but I get an ajax error which is

```
DataTables warning: table id=thetable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

The table and the names are perfectly correct. Is this something because I am using DB select?

Comment: can you simply open http://yourdomain.com/partdetails/serverSide in your browser and see if you are able to view the server response ?

Comment: I am getting an error

`FatalErrorException in EloquentEngine.php line 22: Call to a member function getQuery() on array`